# Calculate coordinates of a point at 90 degrees from a line

Tags: geometry

I know this question must be ridiculous, but I ask for your support.
As you can see in this example of Geogebra (https://ggbm.at/PdARwwsz):

[image: See the image]), I have the line AB in any arrangement within the Cartesian plane and I want to **calculate the coordinates of point C at 90 degrees from point B**.

The simplest way I found was to find the absolute angle of the line with the tangent arc of the slope and then find the final x and y coordinates for point C.

The problem is that when the angle is greater than 90 degrees, the coordinates are reversed:

[image: see the image]

I would like to know if there is a simple and elegant way to always keep the coordinates 90 degrees to the left, regardless of the angle.

Comment: It would be nice to include that graphics in a way permanently accessible to Math:SE users so the question does not lose its context in case the external link becomes invalid. See for example here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-do-i-upload-an-image-for-use-in-a-question

Comment: Looking at the amount of negative points I got from my question, I realize that the staff here is pretty intolerant, is not it?

Comment: People often don't like to click links on public forums because anybody can link something harmful (virus, etc), so providing the pictures for us in the question makes it safer to answer

Comment: I agree, but geogebra is well known and interactive, much better than an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, lets call it
$$v\;:=\;\left(\begin{array}{c}
v^{x}\\
v^{y}
\end{array}\right)$$
A vector orthogonal to $v$ would be given by
$$u\;:=\;\left(\begin{array}{c}
-v^{y}\\
v^{x}
\end{array}\right)$$
In your problem you can calculate $v$ by subtractiong the coordinates of $A$ from $B$ (or the other way around).
You would then have to normalize the vector $u$ by dividing it by its norm:
$$\bar{u}\;:=\;\left(\begin{array}{c}
-v^{y}\\
v^{x}
\end{array}\right) \cdot \left(\left(v^{x}\right)^2 + \left(v^{y}\right)^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
Thus $\bar{u}$ has unit length. You would also make sure the sign of $\bar{u}$ matches the direction in which you want to go from point $B$ (multiply by $-1$ if necessary).
Then you can multiply $\bar{u}$ by $2$ or whatever distance $C$ should have from $B$ and add this to the coordinates of $B$:
$$C = d\cdot \bar{u} + B$$
Where $d$ is scalar accountig for direction (by its sign) and distance (by its magnitude) as explained above.

EDIT: Example calculation

Let $B=\left(2,2\right)^T$ and $A=\left(0,0\right)^T$.

We then have $$v = B - A = B$$
We have $$u=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-2\\
2
\end{array}\right)$$
and furthermore
$$\left|u\right|=\left|v\right|=\left(\left(-2\right)^{2}+2^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{\left(-2\right)^{2}+2^{2}}=\sqrt{8}$$
thus
$$\bar{u}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{8}}\\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{8}}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)
 $$
We want a distance of $2$ between point $C$ and $B$, $\left|C-B\right|\overset{!}{=}2$ and thus $\left|d\right|=2$. But we have to be careful to step in the right direction, that is chose the right sign for $d$.

Using $d=2$ we get:
$$C = 2 \cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
2\\
2
\end{array}\right)\approx\left(\begin{array}{c}
0.59\\
3.41
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, I may be wrong, but I do not think this equation solves what I asked for.
In a simple example, if A = (0,0) and B = (2,2) we have a vector at 45 degrees.
Thus, if the distance "d" for C is = 2, then C = (0.59, 3.41).
I did not understand how to get to these coordinates with your equation.

Comment: I added the example calculation - If you need another example, let me know via comment.

Comment: There's a simple, efficient and elegant solution! Thank you!